# Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. b было 0x1110112

Tags: c++

Есть код, который в итоге должен совершать некую обработку копии динамического двумерного массива. На этапе копирования массива в функции func_copy_mas возникает ошибка <Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. b было 0x1110112>.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int n;
int m;
int** massiv;
int** copymassiv;



void func_copy_mas(int** a, int** b, int n, int m)
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            a[i][j] = b[i][j];        
}


void delete_mas(int** a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[]a[i];
}


void zapol_mas(int** a, int n, int m)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k=0;

    for (i = 0; i < n - k; i++, k++)
        for (j = k; j < m - k; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = i + 1;
            a[n - i - 1][j] = i + 1;
        }

    k = 1;

    for (j = 0; j < m - k; j++, k++)    
        for (i = k; i < n - k; i++)
        {
            a[i][j] = j + 1;
            a[i][m - j - 1] = j + 1;
        }    
}


void vidil_pam_massiv(int** a, int n, int m)
{
    a = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = new int[m];

}


int main()
{
    cout << ("Strok: ");
    cin >> n;
    cout << ("Stolb: ");
    cin >> m;

    vidil_pam_massiv(massiv, n, m);

    func_copy_mas(massiv, copymassiv, n, m);

    zapol_mas(copymassiv, n, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << copymassiv[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    delete_mas(massiv, n);
    delete_mas(copymassiv, n);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Под первый массив память выделена, а под второй? вот и валится...

Comment: А память под массивы указателей кто освобождать будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
void vidil_pam_massiv(int** a, int n, int m) 
{
    a = new int* [n];         //a - параметр функции, а вы его локально 
                              //изменяете, но вызвавшая функцию 
                              //программа ничего об этом не знает.
```

Исправление - передавать a по ссылке:

```
using PArray = int**;

void vidil_pam_massiv(PArray& a, int n, int m)
```

Раз вы пишете на `C++`, используйте `C++`! Для массивов там есть прекрасный `std::vector`